# Problem with exiting a daemonized process

Tags: python, daemon, multiprocessing

I am writing a daemon program that spawns several other children processes. After I run the `stop` script, the main process keeps running when it's intended to quit, this really confused me.

```
import daemon, signal
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count, JoinableQueue
from http import httpserv
from worker import work

class Manager:
    """
    This manager starts the http server processes and worker
    processes, creates the input/output queues that keep the processes
    work together nicely.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = cpu_count()

    def start(self):
        self.i_queue = JoinableQueue()
        self.o_queue = JoinableQueue()

        # Create worker processes
        self.workers = [Process(target=work,
                                args=(self.i_queue, self.o_queue))
                        for i in range(self.NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES)]
        for w in self.workers:
            w.daemon = True
            w.start()

        # Create the http server process
        self.http = Process(target=httpserv, args=(self.i_queue, self.o_queue))
        self.http.daemon = True
        self.http.start()

        # Keep the current process from returning
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            time.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        print "quiting ..."

        # Stop accepting new requests from users
        os.kill(self.http.pid, signal.SIGINT)

        # Waiting for all requests in output queue to be delivered
        self.o_queue.join()

        # Put sentinel None to input queue to signal worker processes
        # to terminate
        self.i_queue.put(None)
        for w in self.workers:
            w.join()
        self.i_queue.join()

        # Let main process return
        self.running = False


import daemon

manager = Manager()
context = daemon.DaemonContext()
context.signal_map = {
        signal.SIGHUP: lambda signum, frame: manager.stop(),
        }

context.open()
manager.start()
```

The `stop` script is just a one-liner `os.kill(pid, signal.SIGHUP)`, but after that the children processes (worker processes and http server process) end nicely, but the main process just stays there, I don't know what keeps it from returning.

Comment: Do you see the "quitting ..." printed out?

Comment: I tried your code as is, minus the daemon module, and it works for me. Can you give a link to your version of the daemon module? A google search reveals a few choices.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, for the daemon module I use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/

Comment: @grieve, I never saw "quiting ...", as stdout and stderr are redirected to a log file when daemonized, but even in the redirected file I didn't see it.

Comment: @Joshua: You're right, my answer from early on wasn't worth the bounty, and I have deleted it. However, I don't think downvoting it was fair. I don't mind the rep loss, I can live with that; I just don't think it's right to downvote an answer that was correct earlier in the process of this question. Leaving me the comment would have been totally enough (that's what brought me here, anyway). And since SO obviously doesn't tell you if a bounty was placed on a question that you answered, I hope you weren't suggesting I was deliberately waiting for the bounty to land before my feet.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a different approach, and this seems to work (note I took out the daemon portions of the code as I didn't have that module installed).

```
import signal

class Manager:
    """
    This manager starts the http server processes and worker
    processes, creates the input/output queues that keep the processes
    work together nicely.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = cpu_count()

    def start(self):

       # all your code minus the loop

       print "waiting to die"

       signal.pause()

    def stop(self):
        print "quitting ..."

        # all your code minus self.running


manager = Manager()

signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, lambda signum, frame: manager.stop())

manager.start()
```

One warning, is that signal.pause() will unpause for any signal, so you may want to change your code accordingly.

**EDIT:**

The following works just fine for me:

```
import daemon
import signal
import time

class Manager:
    """
    This manager starts the http server processes and worker
    processes, creates the input/output queues that keep the processes
    work together nicely.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = 5

    def start(self):

       # all your code minus the loop

       print "waiting to die"
       self.running = 1
       while self.running:
           time.sleep(1)

       print "quit"



    def stop(self):
        print "quitting ..."

        # all your code minus self.running

        self.running = 0


manager = Manager()

context = daemon.DaemonContext()
context.signal_map = {signal.SIGHUP : lambda signum, frame: manager.stop()}

context.open()
manager.start()
```

What version of python are you using?

Comment: I don't do the signal handling manually myself, it's dealt with the daemon module from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/

Answer (score 1):

You create the http server process but don't `join()` it. What happens if, rather than doing an `os.kill()` to stop the http server process, you send it a stop-processing sentinel (`None`, like you send to the workers) and then do a  `self.http.join()`?

**Update**: You also need to send the `None` sentinel to the input queue once **for each worker**. You could try:

```
    for w in self.workers:
        self.i_queue.put(None)
    for w in self.workers:
        w.join()
```

N.B. The reason you need two loops is that if you put the `None` into the queue in the same loop that does the `join()`, that `None` may be picked up by a worker other than `w`, so joining on `w` will cause the caller to block.

You don't show the code for workers or http server, so I assume these are well-behaved in terms of calling task_done etc. and that each worker will quit as soon as it sees a `None`, without  `get()`-ing any more things from the input queue.

Also, note that there is at least [one open, hard-to-reproduce issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue4660) with `JoinableQueue.task_done()`, which may be biting you.

Comment: The while true loop in my code was indeed self.http.join(), but one process didn't quit, then I replaced it with a while true loop, the process still not quitting :(

Comment: See my update. A modified version of your script with my changes terminates correctly, at least in my environment.